# Color barchart by category in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is an illustration of my pandas data frame

```
          chapter                          imdb_rating  book
    Sozin's Comet, Part 4: Avatar Aang          9.8     Fire
    Sozin's Comet, Part 3: Into the Inferno     9.8     Fire
    The Crossroads of Destiny                   9.6     Earth
    Zuko Alone                                  9.5     Earth
    The Avatar and the Fire Lord                9.5     Fire
```

I would like to plot a basic bar chart. With chapter in the x axis, imdb_rating in y axis and color of the bar should be determined by the book column. I would also like to specify the rgb code of the color.

Here is my code.

```
ax = df3.plot.bar(x = 'chapter', y ='imdb_rating', ylim = (8.9,10))
ax.set_xlabel(None)
ax.set_ylabel('Imdb Rating')
ax.set_title('Top Chapters')
```

I need to add the color grouping code to do this.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) in pandas, you can pass any parameters into the plotting backend to tweak your plot.

And according to the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) in matplotlib, you shall pass in a color list to specify the color for each bar.

A simple approach will be like this: Define your colormap first, and compose your color list with `map()`.

```
color_map = {
    'Earth': 'g',
    'Fire': 'r'
}
ax = df3.plot.bar(x='chapter', y='imdb_rating', color=df3.book.map(color_map.get))
```